# QR Code/PHP Ticketing System

Tags: php, qr-code, ticket-system

I have a QR code that is printed out on a ticket in which once it is scanned it goes to this URL bungeedesign.com/ticketvalidatorv1/index.php the page shows if the ticket is valid or not by checking the date that I set matches today's date (current day).

If the set date does not match up with the current day then the page will display "not valid" so this means that the ticket is no longer valid as it doesn't match the current day. Is there any way to keep the same qr code on the ticket with the same URL and have a new date set and have it check if it matches today while the tickets that were used yesterday/previously still be in a invalid status.

The reason I ask this is due to not wasting tickets that have already been printed, as I would have to change the qr code and URL with a different page containg the new set date while the old tickets would simply still point to the old URL in which would forever display invalid which is want I want but just don't want the tickets to become obsolete once the day is over and there's leftovers.

Sorry if this is a little convoluted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save your tickets into a table an use their id to make urls and check if they're valid.

you can also save the person who has the ticket, date range, used date, how many times can be used and ....